# NoSuchJobException when trying to restart a spring batch job

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am running a spring batch job thru `CommandLineRunner`. The way I want my job to run is for every run create a new `JobInstance` and if the `jobExecution` fails to complete, I will rerun the job with `--restart` parameter and it should find the previous execution and resume that `jobExecution` instead of creating a new `jobInstance`.

Below is my JobConfig class.

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
public class JobConfig {

  @Autowired
  List<Job> jobsToRun; //Jobs annotated as a Components

  @Bean
  public CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner(JobLauncher jobLauncher,
      JobRepository jobRepository, JobOperator jobOperator, JobExplorer jobExplorer) {
    return args -> {
      JobParameters parameters = new JobParametersBuilder()
          .addLong("timestamp", System.currentTimeMillis())
          .toJobParameters();
      SimpleCommandLinePropertySource cli = new SimpleCommandLinePropertySource(args);
      jobsToRun.forEach(job -> {
        try {
          if (!cli.containsProperty("restart")) {
            jobLauncher.run(job, parameters);
          } else {
            long jobInstanceId = jobOperator.getJobInstances(job.getName(), 0, 1).get(0);
            long lastExecutionId = jobOperator.getExecutions(jobInstanceId).get(0);
            if (jobExplorer.getJobExecution(lastExecutionId).getStatus() == BatchStatus.FAILED) {
              jobOperator.restart(lastExecutionId);
              log.info("Restarting the job " + job.getName());
            } else {
              log.warn("Cannot restart the job. Job not in Failed state.");
            }
          }
        } catch (JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException | JobRestartException | JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException | JobParametersInvalidException e) {
          log.error(
              "Error occured while running job " + job.getName() + " Reason: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (NoSuchJobException | NoSuchJobInstanceException | NoSuchJobExecutionException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      });

    };
  }
}
```

This configuration collects all my job beans and runs them thru this `CommandLineRunner` bean.

I run the job without the `--restart` parameter and everything runs fine. 
Next, when I fail the job deliberately and try running the same with `--restart` parameter, the app throws a `org.springframework.batch.core.launch.NoSuchJobException: No job configuration with the name [itemJob] was registered`.

[image: BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION table]

I debug thru the program the `jobInstanceId` and the `jobExecutionId` seem to be the right id's. One important thing is that the app does not log anything as an ERROR. I just get this exception at an INFO level. Not sure what am I missing here.

Just to be more clear. I am also including a job component bean here if that may help.

```
@Component
@Slf4j
@Profile("master")
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "item", havingValue = "true")
public class ItemImportJob {

  @Autowired
  private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

  @Autowired
  private ItemRemotePartition itemRemotePartition;

  @Bean
  @Profile("master")
  public Job itemJob() throws Exception {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("itemJob").listener(new JobExecutionListener() {
      @Override
      public void beforeJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
        log.info("Ready to start the job");
      }

      @Override
      public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
        log.info("Job successfully executed.");
      }
    }).incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
        .start(itemRemotePartition.masterStep())
        .build();

  }

}
```

Complete log of NoSuchJobException:

```
2018-02-06 13:29:35.789  INFO 82332 --- [           main] c.a.s.p.b.BulkImportProductApplication   : Started BulkImportProductApplication in 19.762 seconds (JVM running for 21.76)
org.springframework.batch.core.launch.NoSuchJobException: No job configuration with the name [itemJob] was registered
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.MapJobRegistry.getJob(MapJobRegistry.java:66)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy117.getJob(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobOperator.restart(SimpleJobOperator.java:275)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobOperator$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$44ee6049.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:669)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobOperator$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$587272bf.restart(<generated>)
    at com.art.service.product.bulkimportproduct.config.job.JobConfig.lambda$null$0(JobConfig.java:52)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at com.art.service.product.bulkimportproduct.config.job.JobConfig.lambda$commandLineRunner$1(JobConfig.java:44)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:732)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:716)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:703)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:304)
    at com.art.service.product.bulkimportproduct.BulkImportProductApplication.main(BulkImportProductApplication.java:17)
```

Let me know if I can help you out with any other details that might help figure out what is going wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you populating your `JobRegistry`?

Comment: I am not creating or overriding any bean for JobRegistry.

Comment: Using the `JobOperator` to launch a job requires a `JobRegistry`.  It uses it to find the `Job`.  If you don't want to use one, use the `JobLauncher`.

Comment: Ok, Is there a way I can get hold of the parameters that I used to run the previous jobInstance that failed? Because I think I would need the same job parameters if I want to restart the job using jobLauncher right?

Comment: You would.  You’d use the `JobExplorer` to look up previous `JobExecution` instances and get the parameters from there.